# Whats wrong with my drush script when using sql?

Tags: drush

Im running the following via `drush scr`

```
$query = db_query('select node.nid AS nid from {node} node where (type="feed_item") AND (status="0") limit 1');
```

i am getting this error:

> WD php: PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown
>   column 'feed_item' in 'where clause': select node.nid AS nid from
>   [error] {node} node where (type="feed_item") AND (status="0") limit 1;
>   Array ( )  in include() (line 5 of
>   /home/quickstart/websites/xc.dev/deleteme.php). [4.77 sec, 97.55 MB]
>   PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'feed_item' in 'where clause': select node.nid AS
>   nid from {node} node where (type="feed_item") AND (status="0") limit
>   1; Array ( )  in include() (line 5 of
>   /home/quickstart/websites/xc.dev/deleteme.php). Drush command
>   terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error. [4.79 sec, 97.55
>   MB]

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the problem is in the " / ' , try it this way :

```
$q = db_query("
select node.nid AS nid from {node} node where (type='feed_item') 
AND (status=0) limit 1");
```

Comment: yes its my quotes. i was using a single instead of double. "